# How to iterate through a list of objects without repeating the same line of code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Would you know how i can iterate through the self.checkxxx values so that I do not have to repeat the same if else clause over and over again.
I am not sure how to do it if someone could give me an example that could be very useful
Maybe like a for loop but the for loops i have tried have just not worked.
I just get this error: `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable CheckState object`

```
def checkbox_ledVA(self):
        self.LED = 'PASS'
        self.LED_fail = 'FAIL'
        self.checkPWR_rot_va = self.ui.PWR_rot_VA.checkState()
        self.checkPWR_grun_va = self.ui.PWR_grun_VA.checkState()
        self.checkP1_va = self.ui.Port1_VA.checkState()
        self.checkP2_va = self.ui.port2_VA.checkState()
        self.checkP3_va = self.ui.Port3_VA.checkState()
     
        if self.checkPWR_rot_va == 2:
            self.checkPWR_rot_va = self.LED_pass
        else:
            self.checkPWR_rot_va = self.LED_fail
        
        if self.checkPWR_grun_va == 2:
            self.checkPWR_grun_va = self.LED_pass
        else:
            self.checkPWR_grun_va = self.LED_fail

        if self.checkP1_va == 2:
            self.checkP1_va = self.LED_pass
        else:
            self.checkP1_va = self.LED_fail
        
        if self.checkP2_va == 2:
            self.checkP2_va = self.LED_pass
        else:
            self.checkP2_va = self.LED_fail
        
        if self.checkP3_va == 2:
            self.checkP3_va = self.LED_pass
        else:
            self.checkP3_va = self.LED_fail
```

Please give me an example so i can learn and apply it to my program

Comment: Please update your question with the non-working code you have tried and the full error traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispense with the entire if-else section and use a helper function when originally assigning attributes:

```
def checkbox_ledVA(self):
    self.LED = 'PASS'
    self.LED_fail = 'FAIL'

    pass_fail = lambda state: self.LED if state == 2 else self.LED_fail

    self.checkPWR_rot_va = pass_fail(self.ui.PWR_rot_VA.checkState())
    self.checkPWR_grun_va = pass_fail(self.ui.PWR_grun_VA.checkState())
    self.checkP1_va = pass_fail(self.ui.Port1_VA.checkState())
    self.checkP2_va = pass_fail(self.ui.port2_VA.checkState())
    self.checkP3_va = pass_fail(self.ui.Port3_VA.checkState())
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably put the values in a dictionary or list and do something like

```
for i, val in enumerate(self.values):
    if val == 2:
        self.values[i] = self.LED_pass
    else:
        self.values[i] = self.LED_fail
```

Comment: ja, that was very useful but the returned values still came as 2 or 0 instead of pass or fail. but thank you it was nice

Answer (score 1):

Gratuitious one-liner:

```
[
    setattr(
        self,
        "checkP" + attrib + "_va",
        self.LED_pass
        if getattr(self, "checkP" + attrib + "_va") == 2
        else self.LED_fail,
    )
    for attrib in ["WR_rot", "WR_grun", "1", "2", "3"]
]
```

Comment: It would be slightly less gratuitous as a two-liner with `for attrib in ["WR_rot", "WR_grun", "1", "2", "3"]:` on top rather than using a list-comprehension for side-effects only.  Also it would display as one less line.

Comment: true, although this code _could_ be displayed as one line. but I would never use it in real life! stripping away the common prefixes and suffixes is a crime against readability